# Replace the dot between package and version in multiple xml files

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm looking for a regex to use within my powershell script to replace the dot between the package name and version with a "\", as below. Please see if you could help.

Original:

```
<HintPath>$(NugetPackageRoot)\Azure.Corext.3.1.0\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll</HintPath>
```

Expected:

```
<HintPath>$(NugetPackageRoot)\Azure.Corext\3.1.0\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll</HintPath>
```

Comment: please show what you have tired so far ... and how it failed to meet your needs.

Comment: Hi Lee,
I'm able to get the package and version separately when used below ,

$name, $version='VisualCppTools.14.13.26131.1'-split'(?<=[^\d])\.(?=\d)'

Comment: PLEASE, add that info to your Question, not in the comments. the code is hard to read ... and very easy to overlook. ///// also, your code does not match the sample you show. i presume you have several such items, so you likely otta add at least two or three such to your Question.

Comment: please clarify if this is a one off task that only needs to happen to this particular text, or not. If not, can you come up with a rule to identify the package name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
(?=.+?\\[\w.]+\\.+?)\.([\d.]+)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(?=.+?\\[\w.]+\\.+?)`** - Represents positive lookahead asserting whether the regex contains `\w` and `.` character together.
>
> **`([\d.]+)`** - Represents a capturing group capturing the digits along with dot matching literally.

[image]

You can find the demo of the above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/8wCbuD/2)

**Powershell commands:(Feel free to edit the commands according to your requirement)**

```
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $input_path='C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\test.txt'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $output_path='C:\Path\To\MyDesktop\testResult.txt'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $regex='(?=.+?\\[\w.]+\\.+?)\.([\d.]+)'
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $in = Get-Content $input_path
PS C:\Path\To\MyDesktop> $in | Foreach {$_ -replace $regex, '\$1'} | out-file $output_path
```